# Running node project a second time takes a long time to load (On Windows 10)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've been trying to find this problem on Google, but I have not found anything similar. Also, I can confirm this is not the project's fault, as running it in a Ubunutu VM works perfectly every time.

I'll run `node index.js` and the project loads right away in a matter of seconds. however, once I shut that down (with Ctrl-C) and run `node index.js` again the project will take forever to fully start up. It usually takes about a minute to load (which makes debugging very bad)

Any ideas about this?

Comment: have you tried to run your code on a different machine? It might be something unrelated. If you do not have different machine try running it from a virtual machine.

Comment: yes, the code works perfectly on a VM. I've also tried the same thing with a very simple/short node.js (on my Windows PC) file and the same happens

Comment: It would be interesting to see what your logs are saying. Windows logs. With some chance there could be something to dig further. Meanwhile you can run this command from windows terminal with administrative elevation (search for 'cmd' and right click over the item then select 'Run as administrator'). 

Run the following command: 'sfc -scannow'
It could take a while but if it found error in Windows file system it will provide you with a path to a log file. If everything is fine it mean you file system is good, which is a good new. Oh and if it find a problem it will fix it.

Comment: To be clear, this happens with *any* node app you run even if it's just a simple `console.log` line?

Comment: I did a bit more digging around (and 'sfc -scannow') and found out that the problem isn't node starting up, but express shutting down. The specific port will sort of go into a weird 'null' mode until it timeouts and then a new process can be introduced. I'm trying to find a way to close that connection manually, but things like server.close() in express just timeout and don't work

Answer (score 1):

So, I found an answer to this and I'll post it here because there is almost nothing about this problem.

I realized the problem wasn't node starting up, but rather express shutting down. The port couldn't close properly even though it wouldn't show up with netstat. Because of that, when I tried to do server.close() with express, it wouldn't be able to do anything. From an old question on Google, I found that this is from there being a problem with express destroying the sockets, so I ended up doing it manually. This is how my code looks to solve this issue:

```
 server.on('connection', function(socket){
    sockets.push(socket);
})

process.stdin.resume(); //so program doesn't close instantly

process.on('SIGINT', function(){

    sockets.forEach(function(socket) {
        socket.destroy();
    });

    server.close(function(){
        console.log("Express connection closed");
        process.exit();
    });

    setTimeout( function () {
        console.error("Could not close connections in time, forcefully shutting down");
        process.exit(1);
    }, 20*1000);
});
```